# Debian boot partition full. Did I do something wrong?

Tags: linux, debian, partition

This is the first time I've used straight up Debian for a build, and I think I may have screwed up with setting my partitions. My boot partition is completely full now and I can't do basically anything on the system.

Here's the fdisk output:

```
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 477 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: INTEL SSDPEKKW512G7                     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x1b51435e

Device         Boot    Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1          2048   58593279  58591232    28G 83 Linux
/dev/nvme0n1p2      58595326 1000214527 941619202   449G  5 Extended
/dev/nvme0n1p5      58595328   74217471  15622144   7.5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/nvme0n1p6      74219520 1000214527 925995008 441.6G 83 Linux
```

and here's the df output:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  9.2M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1   28G   28G     0 100% /
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme0n1p6  434G   75M  412G   1% /home
tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/1000
```

Any help would be much appreciated! I'm just not sure what to search to find the fix here.

Comment: Boot from a live CD and resize your partitions. It takes quite a bit of time to get things done. Make sure you get a full backup first.

Comment: Please take the [tour]. Stack Overflow is only for _programming_ questions. For general computer questions, try [su].

Comment: have a look at the gparted live cd, which provides partitioning resizing, copying tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. make dir `/home` on `/dev/nvme0n1p6` and move all to `/home`
2. copy `/` to `/dev/nvme0n1p6` (make one root+home)
3. update boot param for boot and mount only `/dev/nvme0n1p6` as root

from live cd.